# How to get credit memo by order id

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to get `credit memo collection` by `order id` in external `php` file in `magento 1.9.x`

Here is my code to get credit memo by order id.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')
              ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId());
foreach($collection as $item) {
    echo $item->getId();
}
```

But it is showing `NULL`

i tried with various example available on `SO` but they didn't help me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check $order->getId() have proper order id and that order have credit memo.

Comment: Yes it have proper order id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the object of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class then you can get the credit memo collection by using `getCreditmemosCollection()` function
eg. `$order->getCreditmemosCollection()`

it will return you all the creditmemo created for the current loaded order...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<?php
    $orderid = 6; //you order id
    $creditMemos = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection');
    $creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderid);
    $creditMemos->setOrder('created_at','DESC');
    $creditMemos->load();

    foreach ($creditMemos as $creditMemo) {
       var_dump($creditMemo->getData());
    }
?>
```

you can remove this line to get full collection.

```
$creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderid);
```